# Wordpress Version 2.9.2 BUG or is it me?

Tags: wordpress

Has anyone noticed that in Version 2.9.2 of wordpress.org there is no facility to choose a page template?

Or has the tag used in the template file changed?

I hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily switch to another theme and then reactivate your original theme. This does some kind of "reset" in custom templates.

I've had this problem as well. Don't remember though which Wordpress version started with this bug.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. I just remember having the same problem with a 2.8.4 wordpress installation, and I saw this solution in Wordpress forums but can't remember the source. It's really ugly, but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than one page template defined in your theme then you should be able to choose it from the 'Attributes' section on the page editing page. I can confirm that's the case on a couple of my sites that run on WP 2.9.2. What do you see when you expand the 'Attributes' section?

Comment: I see Parent and Order and nothing else. I have two pages once called "Template Name: index" and Template Name: about" both with seperate file names. Seems a bit strange because I have 4 other sites which work but they run an older version

Comment: Ok, the templates section isn't shown if get_page_templates() in WordPress doesn't return anything, which is happening here. Looking at the history I can see that a change went into 2.9 where page templates are hidden if they're in a subdirectory of the theme. Is this the case with your theme? If so you'll need to move the page templates into the root directory of your theme.